# HTML Content is not repopulated in RichEditorView input field, when send/edit any particular data In SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui, chat, rich-text-editor

I am working in SwiftUI, and implementing RichEditorView in Chat Module, where user can send message and edit message.
I'm facing issue in both part

1 - When I send message my inout filed is not getting empty, means editor is not reloaded.
[image]

2 - When I edit data is not repopulated in the field it's again reloaded issue.
[image]

Even $text is receiving the updated html content, as send button getting enable but data is not populating.

Could some body please help how to reload the editor post sending message to make it empty of editing to make it repopulated.

I have used editor view like this.

```
struct RichTextEditor: UIViewRepresentable {
    
    class Coordinator: RichEditorDelegate, RichEditorToolbarDelegate {
        
        var parent: RichTextEditor
        var isDefaultFocus: Bool
        @Binding var colorPickerType: ColorPickerType?
        
        init(_ parent: RichTextEditor, isDefaultFocus: Bool = false, colorPickerType: Binding<ColorPickerType?>) {
            self.parent = parent
            self.isDefaultFocus = isDefaultFocus
            self._colorPickerType = colorPickerType
            NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(colorPicked(notification:)), name: AppNotifications.colorPicked, object: nil)
        }
        
        func richEditorTookFocus(_ editor: RichEditorView) {
            
        }
        
        func richEditorLostFocus(_ editor: RichEditorView) {
            
        }
        
        func richEditor(_ editor: RichEditorView, contentDidChange content: String) {
            parent.htmlText = content
        }
        
        func richEditorToolbarChangeTextColor(_ toolbar: RichEditorToolbar) {
            colorPickerType = .text
        }
        
        func richEditorToolbarChangeBackgroundColor(_ toolbar: RichEditorToolbar) {
            colorPickerType = .background
        }
        
        func richEditorToolbarInsertLink(_ toolbar: RichEditorToolbar) {
            if let hasSelection = toolbar.editor?.hasRangeSelection, hasSelection, let href = toolbar.editor?.runJS("document.getSelection().getRangeAt(0).toString()"){
                toolbar.editor?.insertLink(href, title: "Link")
            }
        }
        
        func richEditorDidLoad(_ editor: RichEditorView) {
            editor.setEditorBackgroundColor(UIColor(parent.editorBackgroundColor))
            editor.setEditorFontColor(UIColor(Color.primary))
            if isDefaultFocus {
                editor.focus()
            }
        }
        
        func richEditor(_ editor: RichEditorView, heightDidChange height: Int) {
            withAnimation {
                if CGFloat(height) > parent.maxHeight {
                    parent.height = parent.maxHeight
                } else if CGFloat(height) < parent.minHeight {
                    parent.height = parent.minHeight
                } else if CGFloat(height) != parent.height {
                    parent.height = CGFloat(height)
                }
            }
        }
        
        @objc func colorPicked(notification: NSNotification) {
            if let colorPickerType = notification.userInfo?["colorPickerType"] as? ColorPickerType, let selectedColor = notification.userInfo?["color"] as? UIColor {
                switch colorPickerType {
                case .text :
                    self.parent.toolbar.editor?.setTextColor(selectedColor)
                case .background :
                    self.parent.toolbar.editor?.setTextBackgroundColor(selectedColor)
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator(self, isDefaultFocus: isDefaultFocus, colorPickerType: $colorPickerType)
    }
    
    @Binding var htmlText: String
    @Binding var colorPickerType: ColorPickerType?
    var isDefaultFocus : Bool
    var minHeight: CGFloat
    @Binding var height: CGFloat
    var maxHeight: CGFloat
    let toolbar: RichEditorToolbar = RichEditorToolbar(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 44))
    var editorBackgroundColor = Color.red
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> RichEditorView {
        let editor = RichEditorView(frame: .zero)
        editor.delegate = context.coordinator
        editor.html = htmlText
        editor.isScrollEnabled = true
        editor.placeholder = "Write something..."
        
        toolbar.options = [
            RichEditorDefaultOption.bold,
            RichEditorDefaultOption.italic,
            RichEditorDefaultOption.strike,
            RichEditorDefaultOption.underline,
            RichEditorDefaultOption.textColor,
            RichEditorDefaultOption.textBackgroundColor,
            RichEditorDefaultOption.link,
            RichEditorDefaultOption.orderedList,
            RichEditorDefaultOption.unorderedList,
            RichEditorDefaultOption.indent,
            RichEditorDefaultOption.outdent,
            RichEditorDefaultOption.alignLeft,
            RichEditorDefaultOption.alignCenter,
            RichEditorDefaultOption.alignRight,
        ]
        
        toolbar.editor = editor
        toolbar.delegate = context.coordinator
        
        editor.inputAccessoryView = toolbar
        
        return editor
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: RichEditorView, context: Context) { }

}
```

I am using a library link: https://github.com/cjwirth/RichEditorView

I want to get input field empty when data sent and want to repopulate the content when tap on edit.

Comment: @cjwirth, https://github.com/cjwirth/RichEditorView/issues/267

Answer (score 0):

It can be done through Notification.
When sending message/ edit message then send a notification and receive it to make the input box reload.

Something like this:

```
NotificationCenter.default.post(name: AppNotifications.reloardEditorInputField, object: nil, userInfo: ["htmlText": htmlText])
```